# Create fake indexing column in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the statement:

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c from database.table sample 50;
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
id   col_a   col_b   col_c
1    data    goes    here
2    data    goes    here
3    data    goes    here
4    data    goes    here
5    data    goes    here
6    data    goes    here
```

Basically - I need to create a column for `id` that starts at 1 and auto-increments with each row that's retrieved.

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to add that sequence to the result of the SAMPLE? Is this supposed to be ordered by any of the columns?

Comment: it's only `sample 50` because the actual table is like 5,000,000 rows and I don't want to pull all of them.  In this instance, since we stop at 50 records, I want the rows to literally go 1 to 50. I don't necessarily want it to be "ordered" by anything - the first row should be 1, the second should be 2, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to number those rows, there's no meaning?

Comment: There is for me?  I mean - I'm taking this data and doing something else with it where I need to have an id of some type for each row, which needs to be numerical, and I want it to be in order from `1 to n`.  So, there's a very specific meaning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want the sampled rows numbered:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_field), 
   dt.*
FROM
 (
   SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c 
   FROM database.table
   SAMPLE 50
 ) AS dt
```

Instead of `SAMPLE` you might also use `TOP`, but then it's not random anymore.

Comment: I see - if I take off `SAMPLE` (from my original query + `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a2.submitted_date DESC ) AS id,`), it goes closer to just starting at 1 - but there are still numbers missing from this.  In my test query, removing `SAMPLE 500`, Teradata asks me at 2,000 rows if I want to stop the query, to which i say Yes - the `id` column ends at `2028`, but returns `2000` rows.  Any idea why this is?  Like, I have `id` # 2014, but not 2015, 2016, or 2017, but then I have 2018....

Comment: @BrianPowell: Did you run my nested query? `SAMPLE` is done **after** the `ROW_NUMBER`, that's why you need a Derived Table.

Comment: Yeah this nested query works great for the `sample` or the `top n` syntax.  thank you!  Took me a while to reformat my original query :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by ??) as id, col_a, col_b, col_c
from t;
```

The `??` represents the column/expression the gives the ordering for the `id`.

Comment: Hmm... I can make this function by using something like `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_field ASC ) AS id` - but I'm not sure how to make this start at `1` and go to `n`